# Why does this procedure work?

Tags: inequality

We know that $$c\geq 0 \implies (|a|<c \iff -c<a<c).$$ May I know why does the following procedure $$|x|<2x \iff -2x<x<2x \iff (0<3x)~\wedge~(0<x) \iff x>0$$ work despite $2x$ not guaranteed to be non-negative all the time?

Answer (score 2):

If $x\leq 0$ then  none of the inequalities is true. So the equivalence is valid in this case.

Answer (score 1):

On the opposite, $x$ *is* guaranteed to be non-negative, from

$$2x>|x|\ge0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Because $$|f(x)|<g(x)\Leftrightarrow -g(x)<f(x)<g(x)$$ for all $x\in D(f)\cap D(g),$ where $D(f)$ is a domain of $f$.